# Having cors error on Nodejs API triggers even after the nginx configuration to the EC2 instance of AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, express, amazon-ec2

I have setup vuejs front-end on the ec2 instance of aws and it is working successfully. But has cors error when nodejs api is called.

Here is my nginx config:

```
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  # vue app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /app/front-end/front-end/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;

     }
  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;


 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;
  }
}
```

> And I am encountering error in browser like this:
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/products' from origin 'http://ec2-**-***-***-**.eu-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.

Here is my nodejs server.js file.

```
const morgan = require("morgan");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config.env" });
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//  Populate req.cookies
app.use(cookieParser());
// Express session
// app.use(
//      session({
//              secret: "mamotechnolabs",
//              resave: true,
//              saveUninitialized: true,
//      })
// );
//  Session setup
app.use(
        session({
                secret: "mamotechnolabs",
                cookie: {
                        maxAge: 600000,
                        secure: true,
                },
                saveUninitialized: false,
                resave: false,
                unset: "destroy",
        })
);

app.use(
        cors({
                origin: ["http://localhost:8080", "https://localhost:8080"],
                credentials: true,
                exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
        })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
        .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
        var hour = 3600000;
        // req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour);
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = hour;
        console.log(req.session);
        next();
});

// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//cors enable functions
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "ec2-**-***-***-**.eu-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
//routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, console.log("Server is running on port: " + port));
```

Also help me on how to make this environment available on Public IPv4 DNS.